# How to reset text on automatically created buttons android studio

Tags: java, android, button, text, tic-tac-toe

I am currently implementing a tic tac toe game for Android in one of my class. When a player clicks one of the "grid" buttons, the button Text is set to whichever symbol this player is (X or O). One of the requirements is to have our game buttons generated automatically on start. So none of the grid buttons have actual ids before the start of the app.

No problem here, until I have to reinitialize the game. Once a winner is declared, I need to reset the grid buttons' text so that it doesn't show X or O on any of them anymore. The thing is, the buttons don't have any ID so it's not as easy as

button.setText("");

I should also add that our professor wants us to use our own Button class (BoutonCase) that implements onClickListener and inherits from Button. Not that it matters in this case. Here's a portion of the code.

```
public class ticTacToeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

int compteur = 0;
LinearLayout ligneColonne1;
LinearLayout ligneColonne2;
LinearLayout ligneColonne3;
boolean JOUEUR_X = true;
int[][] statutJeu = new int[3][3];
Button btnReinitialiser;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tictactoe, container, false);
    int cpt = 0;
    ligneColonne1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ligne1);
    ligneColonne2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ligne2);
    ligneColonne3 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ligne3);
    btnReinitialiser = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnReinit);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btnReinitialiser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            reinitialiserJeu();
        }
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        final BoutonCase button = new BoutonCase(this.getContext());
        button.setId(cpt);
        final int positionCourante = i;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(JOUEUR_X){
                    button.setText("X");
                    statutJeu[1][positionCourante] = 1;
                    JOUEUR_X = false;
                }
                else{
                    button.setText("0");
                    statutJeu[1][positionCourante] = 3;
                    JOUEUR_X = true;
                }
                button.setEnabled(false);
                verifierGagnant();
            }
        });
        ligneColonne1.addView(button, lp);
        cpt++;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        final BoutonCase button = new BoutonCase(this.getContext());
        button.setId(cpt);
        final int positionCourante = i;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(JOUEUR_X){
                    button.setText("X");
                    statutJeu[1][positionCourante] = 1;
                    JOUEUR_X = false;
                }
                else{
                    button.setText("0");
                    statutJeu[1][positionCourante] = 3;
                    JOUEUR_X = true;
                }
                button.setEnabled(false);
                verifierGagnant();
            }
        });
        ligneColonne2.addView(button, lp);
        cpt++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        final BoutonCase button = new BoutonCase(this.getContext());
        button.setId(cpt);
        final int positionCourante = i;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(JOUEUR_X){
                    button.setText("X");
                    statutJeu[2][positionCourante] = 1;
                    JOUEUR_X = false;
                }
                else{
                    button.setText("0");
                    statutJeu[2][positionCourante] = 3;
                    JOUEUR_X = true;
                }
                button.setEnabled(false);
                verifierGagnant();
            }
        });
        ligneColonne3.addView(button, lp);
        cpt++;
    }

    final Button button = new Button(this.getContext());
    button.setId(cpt);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        }
    });return v;
}

public void onClick(View v){
}

void verifierGagnant(){
    //Horizontal --- row
    Toast toastGagnant;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(statutJeu[i][0] == statutJeu[i][1] && statutJeu[i][0] == statutJeu[i][2]){
            if (statutJeu[i][0]==1){
                toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur X a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
                toastGagnant.show();
                break;
            }
            else if (statutJeu[i][0]==3) {
                toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur 0 a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
                toastGagnant.show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Vertical --- columns
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(statutJeu[0][i] == statutJeu[1][i] && statutJeu[0][i] == statutJeu[2][i]){
            if (statutJeu[0][i]==1){
                toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur X a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
                toastGagnant.show();
                break;
            }
            else if (statutJeu[0][i]==3) {
                toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur 0 a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
                toastGagnant.show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //First diagonal
    if(statutJeu[0][0] == statutJeu[1][1] && statutJeu[0][0] == statutJeu[2][2]){
        if (statutJeu[0][0]==1){
            toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur X a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
            toastGagnant.show();
        }
        else if (statutJeu[0][0]==3) {
            toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur 0 a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
            toastGagnant.show();
        }
    }

    //Second diagonal
    if(statutJeu[0][2] == statutJeu[1][1] && statutJeu[0][2] == statutJeu[2][0]){
        if (statutJeu[0][2]==1){
            toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur X a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
            toastGagnant.show();
        }
        else if (statutJeu[0][2]==3) {
            toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Joueur 0 a gagné !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT  );
            toastGagnant.show();
        }
    }
    compteur++;
    if(compteur == 9){
        toastGagnant = Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Partie Null !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toastGagnant.show();
    }
}

 void reinitialiserJeu (){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; i++ ){
                statutJeu[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
         compteur = 0;
    }
```

Comment: You know what.. I had also made a tic-tac-toe game, why are you using a gridview? you can simply take 9 buttons

Comment: you can try this in the OnResume()

Comment: I am not using gridview. I am using 3 linear layouts (horizontal) inside a vertical linear layout to generate buttons automatically. When I say "grid", I am referring to the play area. I can't simply use 9 buttons, because the professor does not want us to use the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You could save all your buttons in a `ArrayList<BoutonCase> buttons;`

Then add your buttons:

```
final BoutonCase button = new BoutonCase(this.getContext());
buttons.add(button);
```

and when you want to reset the game you loop all of them and set their text.

```
for (BoutonCase button : buttons) {
        button.setText(""); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did exactly that and it worked like a charm. At least for this particular case.

Comment: Glad it helped.